# Celery doesn't return or fail when calling apply_async. Works with celery_beat

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I have a problem with calling celery tasks with apply_async.
I have in settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'confirm_publish': True}
CELERY_BROKER_URL = env('RABBITMQ_URL')
print(CELERY_BROKER_URL) //pyamqp://un:pw@app-rabbitmq:5672
CELERY_TASK_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default', type='direct'), routing_key='default'),
    Queue('email', Exchange('email', type='direct'), routing_key='email'),
)
CELERY_TASK_ROUTES = {
    'core.services.CoreSendEmailTaskService.*': {
        'exchange': 'email',
        'routing_key': 'email'
    },
}
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']

CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_TASK_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_RESULT_EXPIRES = 600
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = env('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND_URL') //redis://app-redis:6379/3
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = False

CELERY_WORKER_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 65
CELERY_WORKER_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 60
CELERY_WORKER_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
```

In project_config/celery_config/tasks/__init__.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app

__all__ = ('app',)
```

and in project_config/celery_config/tasks/celery.py:

```
class CeleryApp(celery.Celery):
    def on_configure(self):
        sentry_dns = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SENTRY_DNS', None)

        if sentry_dns and os.environ.get('ENVIRONMENT', 'local') == 'production':
            client = raven.Client(
                sentry_dns
            )

            register_logger_signal(client)
            register_signal(client)


app = CeleryApp('tasks')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


class CeleryTasksConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'project_config.celery_config.tasks'
    verbose_name = 'Celery Tasks'

    def ready(self):
        app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
        app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

The weird thing is that the task executes on staging and production but locally it doesn't. Also locally when scheduled with beat the task runs normally.

The worker is locally started with command:
`celery -A project_config.celery_config.tasks worker -O fair --loglevel=DEBUG --maxtasksperchild=1000 --queues=default,email -P prefork`

Comment: First, I see a typo in your settings: "ELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT", maybe not related to your problem.  Second, I see no detail here that looks out of the ordinary or would explain the problem you are having. (Other than the fact that you've got celery.py in as a task, I would move it up a level). We may need more information.  Also, what is the value of ENVIRONMENT when running in staging?

Comment: How are you starting celery on your local system?

Comment: @BillHuneke Yes, that was a copy paste error, I've edited the post, ty.

@2ps celery starts locally with:

```celery -A project_config.celery_config.tasks worker -O fair --loglevel=DEBUG  --maxtasksperchild=1000  --queues=default,email,kraken -P prefork```


and on staging/production with:

```celery -A project_config.celery_config.tasks worker -O fair --loglevel=INFO  --maxtasksperchild=1000 --concurrency=4 --queues=default,email -P prefork```

Comment: @BillHuneke The value of ENVIRONMENT is staging on staging and production on production